# Input text not being passed down to the right function

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

Something is wrong when I run this code, I think the Onclick event and my HTML is formatted incorrectly with 2 functions.
Only the upsTrackNo input is working but the other 4 fields aren't.
The 4 fields that contain address info should be passed down to **getUPSXMLAddressValidation** function and the upsTtrackNo to the **getUPSTrackingDetails** function when the button is pressed.
Thank you in advance!

```
<div>
    Address: <br>
    <input type="text" id="Address" runat="server"/>
    <br/>
    City: <br>
    <input type="text" id="City" runat="server"/>
    <br/>
    State: <br>
    <input type="text" id="State" runat="server"/>
    <br/>
    Zipcode: <br>
    <input type="text" id="Zipcode" runat="server"/>
    <br/>
    <input type="text" id="upsTrackNo" placeholder="ups tracking #" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="upsTrackButton" Text="Submit" OnClick="GetUpsTrackingDetails;getUPSXMLAddressValidation" runat="server" />
</div>
```

Comment: You should call a single function from the asp OnClick.  You can call the other function from within that function.

Comment: OnClick event calls code behind functions. You cannot call 2 methods from 1 OnClick event. That only works in OnClientClick when calling JavaScript methods. Limit your Onclick call to GetUpsTrackingDetails and call getUPSXMLAddressValidation before you do anything else in GetUpsTrackingDetails.